# Azure Storage set CacheControl by default

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, cache-control

**The Objective:**

I would like to set by default an expiration time for each file that we have stored in the Storage and for the new ones that we will add.

**The problem:**

Using the Azure portal we can change the expiration time but file by file and we can't set an expiration time by default.. ><' so the only way that could be done is creating a WebJob that will be triggered on the creation of an elemet. "great"

I've seen examples where you can resize an image and store it again on a different folder using input and output parameters but I would like to use only the input parameter in order to modify the property and save it, but each time that I've to stop and turn on the WebJob or I've to add a new file it executes the Trigger again for all items,

**The Code:**

```
 public static void UpdateCouldBlockBlob([BlobTriggerAttribute("img/{name}.{ext}")] CloudBlockBlob cloudBLockBlob)
        {
            cloudBLockBlob.Properties.CacheControl = "public, max-age=604801";
            cloudBLockBlob.SetProperties();
        }
```

Comment: Can't you set the cache control property on the blob to the desired value when the blob is created?

Comment: Srry Gaurav, I can't understand your question,